# Chrome could not load google talk plugin

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

My Chrome version is 35.0.1916.114 in Ubuntu 14.04. I tried the .deb package in Google talk plugin website and the method in the last post of this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium/+bug/1302793.
However, the problem still exists. How can I solve it?

Comment: Is this google hangouts? (http://www.google.co.uk/hangouts/)

Answer (score 0):

The long and short of this is that you cannot - at least with any new version from Google Chrome v35 and onwards.

Google consider the mechanism it used - [NPAPI](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html) - to be a security risk and is not part of modern browser technology.

From v35 they have effectively [turned off support](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Px-7ASU8Sn4) for NPAPI plugins.  Google-Talk is one of these plugins.  Standard Adobe Flash is another.

The replacement for Google Talk is now [Google Hangouts](http://www.google.co.uk/hangouts/) and as such they are pushing you towards that direction.

Obviously, you can try to download an older version of Google Chrome e.g. v34 - but remember these old versions are no longer patched, so you'll be opening yourself to security risks whilst browsing.